# reading info from text file and passing read lines to urlencode python function

Tags: python

I'm trying to send urlencode() data to my web server.
The data used for the urlencode() function is read from a text file located on my local machine.
When I read the input data for the urlencode() function from the .py script no error is being thrown.
However, if the input data for the urlencode() function is comming from a local input text file I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "active_directory_ssl_test.py", line 30, in 
    params = urllib.urlencode(dict(LINE))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

I'm doing the following:

```
FILE=open(IN_FILE, 'r')
LINE = FILE.readline()
while LINE:
    print LINE
    LINE = FILE.readline()
    params = urllib.urlencode(dict(LINE))
    try:
        f_handler = urlopen('https://host_name/path_name/file_name', params)
```

Why is there a difference, an error, when reading data from a text file. In both cases a variable is used as a parameter to the urlencode() function.

This is the content of the input text file:

```
{'hostname' : 'host.1.com', 'port' : '389', 'basedn' : 'CN=Users,DC=prem,DC=local', 'username' : 'CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=onprem,DC=local', 'password' : 'passwd', 'roupname' : 'CN=Group,CN=Users,DC=onprem,DC=local', 'attribute' : 'name', 'enabled' : 'sync', 'impsync' : 'sync', 'enabled' : 'enabled', 'username' : 'user@1.com', 'password' : 'passwd', 'update' ; 'update'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and post my comment as an answer, as it is the answer.  You're calling `dict()` on a string.  The `dict()` function expects one of two types of input.  Either A. a list of tuples that form `(key, value)` pairs, or B. keyword arguments that come in the form `key = value`.  You're not passing either of those.

-- Extra detail for the Comments --

```
>>> input = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> type(input)
<type 'dict'>
>>> dict(input)
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
>>> input = "{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}" # This is your 2nd form.
>>> type(input)
<type 'str'>
>>> dict(input)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Also, for what it's worth, in your first example the call to `dict()` is superfluous.  You already have a dictionary which was declared using literal syntax.

Comment: Hi, then why does the urlencode() function work this way:    input = {'val1' : 'value1', 'val2' : 'value2'}                              params = urllib.urlencode(dict(input))     I also only pass a string to the urlencode() function and it works correctly. In this case the input is listed in the .py script

Comment: @roland - When you have `{'hostname': 'host.1.com'}` in a .py file it's a literal declaration of a dictionary.  When you read a line from a file, you read it as a string, which would be the functional equivalent of `"{'hostname': 'host.1.com'}"`.  The two are distinctly different.

Comment: @roland - You've only accepted answers (clicked the check mark) for 25% of the questions you've asked.  While 100% is not required, you should strive to indicate when your questions have been answered. Please refer to this FAQ Article:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers